# if else in react native

Tags: react-native, if-statement

I am new to react native. I Have created a screen where I am using if else in function like this.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
     phpid = ''
}
}

validateInputs = (event) => {
  
  const data = this.props.route.params.data
  const { phpid } = this.state;


if (data.retail_information_data[0] != '') {
      phpid == data.retail_information_data[0].id  
}else{
      phpid == null
}
 
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["application_id", "created_by"]).then(response => {
  
       console.log(phpid)

  fetch('https://njdnfech/Android_API_CI/uploaddata/tffmerchant_retail_details?query=', {
    
      body: JSON.stringify([{phpid : phpid}])
    })
    .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
    .then(function(response) {
     console.log(response)
      return response.json();
}
```

but I am getting  = data.retail_information_data[0] = null or lets say empty
then according to if else my else condition that is 'phpid == null' shuld run
but even 'data.retail_information_data[0] = null' my else condition not running my console kepp saying
'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.retail_information_data[0].id')'
is any problem in my if else or how to write proper if else

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using ternary operator.
phpid = data.retail_information_data[0] ? data.retail_information_data[0].id  : null

Comment: Well Yes you can't set state directly. I don't have much idea about class components. Like if you use functional components you have setPhpid from which you can Update state. Serch for how.you can set state using class components.

Comment: thanku its work I just add const before php id thanku very mush

Answer (score 0):

The below should work...

```
if (data && data?.retail_information_data.length) {
    this.setState(phpid: data?.retail_information_data[0]?.id)
    }else{
          this.setState(phpid: null)
    }
```